# Can't Return values in Apex from Flow Winter 19

Tags: apex, invocable-method, winter19, spring-20, invocablevariable

I'm trying to refactor a flow I built in Spring 20, back to Winter 19. In Spring 20, I can just create a resource for my Apex Output. I've called this variable `{!apexReturnedObj}`

I'm trying do some simple logic like  `{!apexReturnedObj.Id}` Was Set {!GlobalConstant.true}

This format works in Spring 20, but not Winter 19. Anyone know how to refactor it back?

**Error Message**

`The flow couldn't find the "apexReturnedObj" resource.`

Comment: Is there a specific error message you're getting?

Comment: Yes. It is sending an error that says the flow couldn't find the "ApexReturnObj" resource.

Comment: What's your store output values screen look like for when you set `apexReturnObj`?

Comment: Hey @KrisGoncalves after doing more debugging, it turned out it was working as should be and the logic in the SOQL query was not returning a variable and therefore was not finding anything in the variable.

Comment: Given this was most likely user error on my part, what is #stackExchange best practice. Do you delete posts like this or do you just close them out?

Comment: You can just leave the answer to what the issue was even if it ended up not being what you expected. It's helpful in case someone else tries looking up their error message and matches it to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this turned out to be user error on my part.

In short there were two things in my case that contributed.

One I originally built this in a sandbox that was on Spring 20 and had to deploy to a Sandbox for training that was still running Winter 19.

Second, I had no data relevant to the SOQL query that was being called in the `Invocable Method`. The Data that it was looking for was 'already existing' data that would have been created by the flow if it had been running on a Spring 19. In short, it was a bit of a challenge to debug because it was unclear if the Apex was failing or if it was still the flow that was failing. Hence the regular occurrence of not finding the data in the output variable in the method.

Thanks for the help again @KrisGoncalves